# GWT vertical menu

Tags: java, gwt

I need some help with Google web toolkit to make a vertical menu with expanding submenu items.

I want to create a vertical menu that woks like the left menu on the [showcase of GWT](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html)

I tried this:

```
VerticalPanel vertpanel = new VerticalPanel();
MenuBar menubar = new MenuBar(true);//set to true so its set to vertical alignment
MenuBar subbar = new MenuBar(true);
MenuBar subbar2 = new MenuBar(true);
subbar.addItem("Fist item of submenu1", new AddEmployeeCommand());
subbar.addItem("Second item of submenu1", new AddEmployeeCommand());
subbar2.addItem("First item of submenu2", new AddEmployeeCommand());
subbar2.addItem("Second item of submenu2", new AddEmployeeCommand());
menubar.addItem("sub 1", subbar);
menubar.addItem("sub 2", subbar2);
vertpanel.add(menubar);
RootPanel.get().add(menubar);
```

But that doesn't work because the menu items won't expand to show their subitems. Although it works when I make it a horizontal menubar but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use `DisclosurePanel`s in order to achieve that.

Check it out in the [GWT showcase](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDisclosurePanel).

Answer (score 1):

That's probably using a DosclosurePanel, not a Menu Bar.

http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDisclosurePanel

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can have a look to a `StackPanel`

[Gwt Stackpanel showcase](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwStackPanel)